# How to replace a reference with an in memory reference?

Tags: c#, roslyn

Using Roslyn, I'm taking a solution with two projects (A/B), modifying B, then calling into A with the expectation that when A calls B it will get the new modified result.

B has `Console.WriteLine("Hello");` and I want to update it to `Console.WriteLine("Hello World");`.  So that when A calls into B I see an output of `Hello World` in the console output.

1) For `A` I store the `CSharpCompilation`

2) For `B` I modify the `SyntaxTree`, modify it, then return a new `CSharpCompilation`

```
return CSharpCompilation.Create(
    $"{compilation.AssemblyName}.dll",
    options: new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.DynamicallyLinkedLibrary),
    syntaxTrees: modifiedSyntaxTrees,
    references: compilation.References
);
```

3) I then take the `CSharpCompilation` for `B` and call `ToMetadataReference`

4) I then call `CSharpCompilation.ReplaceReference` on `A`, providing the output from step 3.

5) When I then try to create a new `Assembly` for A I get this error `BadImageFormatException: Bad IL format.`:

```
private static Assembly CreateAssemblyFromCompilation(CSharpCompilation compilation)
{
    Assembly compiledAssembly;
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var emitResult = compilation.Emit(stream);
        compiledAssembly = Assembly.Load(stream.GetBuffer());
    }

    return compiledAssembly;
}
```

I have also tried `MetadataReference.CreateFromImage` which results in the same error.